# Append bytes to MemoryStream without moving the position

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm trying to append data to a MemoryStream with the Write(); Method
But that Also moves the Position. I know I can change the Position manually.
But is there a way to append data to a MemoryStream without moving the Position

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[20];
                Random rand = new Random();
                rand.NextBytes(data);

                stream.Write(data, 0, 20);
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt32());//Pointer = 20 here
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: No, a read or write logically advances the current position. You can set it back by the amount of bytes written, if that's what you want and the stream supports it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a MemoryStream does not have any functionality to do that on it's own. For a stream, this is also the logical behavior.

But that also means that there is nothing wrong if you are doing this yourself. If your intention is to have some kind of nice way of reusing this functionality, I'd recommend writing a simple extension method for `MemoryStream`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void WriteAndResetPosition(this MemoryStream stream, byte[] data, int offset, int count)
    {
        stream.Write(data, offset, count);
        stream.Position -= count;
    }    
}
```

That's brain compiled code :), so take it with a grain of salt. After that, you can use it like:

```
stream.WriteAndResetPosition(data, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Brain-compiled code... mine always includes recursion.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger That's fine as long as it is not brain-executed!